# Prove that the number of automorphisms from $E$ to $E$ that fixes $F$ is equal to $[E:F]$ .

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be a finite extension and it is a Galois extension.

Prove that the number of automorphisms from $E$ to $E$ that fixes $F$ is equal to $[E:F]$ .

I cant start at all.How should I begin?

Comment: Just a half-baked thought, but since $n = [E:F]$ is the dimension of $E$ as a vector space over $F$, you might want to choose $n$ linearly independent elements of $E$, say $b_1, \ldots, b_n$, which form a basis for $E$ as a vector space over $F$.

Comment: The case of infinite characteristic or finite fields is particularly simple due to the primitive element theorem. The general theorem is usually proven through something like independence of characters and will be proven in almost every galois theory text. It is one of the foundational results of the subject.

Comment: What will that do ?@JohnHughes

Comment: I agree with Asvin. It is difficult to imagine a text on Galois theory that would not prove this. And to know how you should begin depends on what you already know about Galois extensions.